# How to access UI elements from UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I am just starting to move from the Interface Builder to 100% code.

I have successfully been able to create an Auto Layout single screen application as a proof of concept. The thing is, I feel as if there is a much more efficient way of doing this.

What is the proper way of getting objects from a UIView class and accessing then in a `UIViewController` ?

Here is the code to my whole project

**AppDelegate.swift**.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

**ViewControllerView.swift**

```
import UIKit

public enum ViewControllerTextFields: String {
    case username = "usernameField"
    case password = "passwordField"
}

public enum ViewControllerButtons: String {
    case login = "loginButton"
}

class ViewControllerView: UIView {

    private var views = [String: UIView]()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .lightGray
        createScreenComponents()
        createConstraints()
    }

    func makeTextField(withPlaceholder text: String, textColor color: UIColor) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.attributedPlaceholder =  NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [.foregroundColor : color.withAlphaComponent(0.5)])
        textField.textColor = color
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return textField
    }

    func makeButton(withTitle title: String) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        return button
    }

    func createScreenComponents() {
        let usernameField = makeTextField(withPlaceholder: "Username", textColor: .white)
        let passwordField = makeTextField(withPlaceholder: "Password", textColor: .white)

        let loginButton = makeButton(withTitle: "Login")

        views["usernameField"] = usernameField
        views["passwordField"] = passwordField
        views["loginButton"] = loginButton
    }

    func createConstraints() {
        for (key, val) in views {
            addSubview(val)
            addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
                withVisualFormat: "H:|[\(key)]|",
                options: [],
                metrics: nil,
                views: views)
            )
        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "V:|[usernameField]",
            options: [],
            metrics: nil,
            views: views)
        )

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "V:[usernameField][passwordField(==usernameField)]",
            options: [],
            metrics: nil,
            views: views)
        )

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "V:[passwordField][loginButton(==passwordField)]|",
            options: [],
            metrics: nil,
            views: views)
        )

    }

    public func getTextFieldWithId(_ identifier: ViewControllerTextFields) -> UITextField {
        return views["\(identifier.rawValue)"] as! UITextField
    }

    public func getButtonWithID(_ identifier: ViewControllerButtons) -> UIButton {
        return views["\(identifier.rawValue)"] as! UIButton
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var username: UITextField!
    var password: UITextField!

    override func loadView() {
        let viewObject = ViewControllerView()
        view = viewObject

        username = viewObject.getTextFieldWithId(.username)
        password = viewObject.getTextFieldWithId(.password)

        viewObject.getButtonWithID(.login).addTarget(self, action: #selector(test), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @objc func test() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}
```

Is there a way to access the ViewControllerView objects such as a UITextFields and UIButtons without having to use the `viewObject` variable and using functions to return the views?

Comment: Depending on how many subviews are in the main view of the view controller, you can either (1) declare them as `UIViewController` variables, instantiate and add them to the main view using `view.addSubview()`, set their autoresizing mask to false,  and then set their constraints. (2) But if you have a large amount of views you could store them in an array typed as `Any` by instantiating them with a `tag` property associated to the array position, and you can check that tag in processing things. Be sure to type cast using `as` to the correct view. Besides the declaration, use `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: @dfd 1) I do not want to create and display the elements in viewDidLoad because that would mean that I have to put all the code for creating the UI in the ViewController class. I am laying it out like this because I want to keep my program logic in ViewController and the UI layout code in the UIView class.

Comment: I didn't quite catch that. :-) Looking at your `ViewControllerView` class - I'd rename it to something like `PasswordView` - you can do two things - expose the views themselves or expose string properties as read only. In the former (probably easiest) you'd access the text in the views directly from the controller, and in the latter (probably more MVC) you'd move the logic needed (say, for a password check) into the view and the controller would do the processing.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your question... Are you saying you want to be able to load a UIView subclass and be able to refer to the subviews and properties of that class as if they were owned by the ViewController? Such as `let t = username.text` instead of `let t = viewObject.username.text`?

Comment: @DonMag Yes. For example, when we use the interface builder, I reference the text field with `@IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!` or something like that anyway. By doing it through 100% code, as far as I know, I need to reference the text field from the view object itself.

Comment: Hmmm... in IB, if you have a custom view - that contains IBOutlets - as a subview of your view controller, you cannot make them IBOutlets of the VC. If you just mean you're adding views as subviews of the VC, and then making those views IBOutlets of your ***VC*** itself, then the "100% code" model would be to put those in your ViewController and just add them to the default view, *not* in a separate UIView subclass.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to hold private variables of the textfields and buttons in ViewController View, but provide read-only variables that can be accessed in the controller,

In ViewControllerView.swift:

```
private var _username: UITextField!
private var _password: UITextField!
private var _login: UIButton!

var username: UITextField! { get { return _username } }
var password: UITextField! { get { return _password } }
var login: UIButton! { get { return _login } }
```

Then in ViewController.swift, you can substitute the following lines:

```
username = viewObject.getTextFieldWithId(.username)
password = viewObject.getTextFieldWithId(.password)

viewObject.getButtonWithID(.login).addTarget(self, action: #selector(test), for: .touchUpInside)
```

with:

```
username = viewObject.username
password = viewObject.password

viewObject.login.addTarget(self, action: #selector(test), for: .touchUpInside)
```

You could even store these variables as instance variables in the ViewController class if you wish.

Comment: That looks cleaner than my code, however, I still need to create the viewObject and then set self.view equal to the viewObject. What I hoped that I could do was to completely get rid of `viewObject`.

Comment: I believe the only way you can do that is if you (in the interface builder) set the class of the view to ViewControllerView.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a much more logical - and easier - way to go about it:

```
// Typical AppDelegate.swift for running WITHOUT storyboard

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }

}
```

---

```
// our start-up View Controller

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var theVCView = ViewControllerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // replace "default" view with our custom view
        self.view = theVCView

        // example of adding a "Call Back" closure to "hear from" and get access to the custom view elements
        theVCView.buttonCallBackAction = {
            _ in
            var sUsername = ""
            var sPassword = ""
            if let t = self.theVCView.usernameField.text {
                sUsername = t
            }
            if let t = self.theVCView.passwordField.text {
                sPassword = t
            }
            print("Username:", sUsername)
            print("Password:", sPassword)
            // do whatever else you want here...
        }

    }

}
```

---

```
// and... our custom UIView

import UIKit

class ViewControllerView: UIView {

    lazy var usernameField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.attributedPlaceholder =  NSAttributedString(string: "Username", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : (UIColor.white).withAlphaComponent(0.5)])
        textField.textColor = .white
        return textField
    }()

    lazy var passwordField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.attributedPlaceholder =  NSAttributedString(string: "Password", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : (UIColor.white).withAlphaComponent(0.5)])
        textField.textColor = .white
        return textField
    }()

    lazy var loginButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    // optional "Call Back" closure
    var buttonCallBackAction : (()->())?

    func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        buttonCallBackAction?()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        self.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        createConstraints()
    }

    func createConstraints() {
        let views = [
            "usernameField": usernameField,
            "passwordField": passwordField,
            "loginButton": loginButton
        ] as [String : UIView]

        for (key, val) in views {
            addSubview(val)
            addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
                withVisualFormat: "H:|[\(key)]|",
                options: [],
                metrics: nil,
                views: views)
            )
        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "V:|-80-[usernameField][passwordField(==usernameField)][loginButton(==passwordField)]",
            options: [],
            metrics: nil,
            views: views)
        )

    }

}
```

---

Now, you have properties of your custom view that you can access in the "normal" way.

Comment: Except if you have many buttons, you are creating code blocks instead of functions. It is easier to find functions than variable which are code blocks.